# making a std::tuple from the result of a pack

Tags: c++, tuples

Suppose I'm writing a function called 'invoke_all', which applies all the lambdas it receives (as template parameters) to the arguments, it looks like:

```
template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  (std::invoke(fs, std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...);
}
```

so far so good. call it like:

```
invoke_all<
      [](auto i, auto j) { std::println("lambda1: {} {}", i, j); },
      [](auto i, auto j) { std::println("lambda2: {} {}", i, j); }
      >
      (42, "abc"s);
```

but suppose I actually want those lambdas to return values, and pack all the return values in a std::tuple, the problem arises. This doesn't compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{(std::invoke(fs, std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...)};
}

using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    auto results = invoke_all< //
        [](auto i, auto j) { return std::format("lambda1: {} {}", i, j); },
        [](auto i, auto j) { return std::format("lambda2: {} {}", i, j); }> //
    (42, "abc"s);

    assert((results == std::tuple{"lambda1: 42 abc"s, "lambda2: 42 abc"s}));
}
```

because the tuple that 'invoke_all' returns, is a tuple of size 1, not 2.

and this doesn't compile either:

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{std::invoke(fs, std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...};
}

using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    auto results = invoke_all< //
        [](auto i, auto j) { return std::format("lambda1: {} {}", i, j); },
        [](auto i, auto j) { return std::format("lambda2: {} {}", i, j); }> //
    (42, "abc"s);

    assert((results == std::tuple{"lambda1: 42 abc"s, "lambda2: 42 abc"s}));
}
```

because the missing () around the pack expansion (I think).

So is there a way out of this, i.e., making a tuple from the result pack expansion?

Comment: You have a common typo, extra `,` in the second snippet.

Comment: Your CTAD might have unexpected results (e.g., if you have a single function returning a tuple, `invoke_all` will return that tuple instead of a tuple containing that tuple). Also it copies from functions that return references. Suggest you use `return std::tuple<std::invoke_result_t<decltype((fs)), Args&...>...>(std::invoke(fs, args...)...)`

Comment: First attempt is using comma operator, so result is tuple with single value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it with your last attempt.  The thing you need to remember is that `...` means expand into a comma separated list so when you do

```
template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{std::invoke(fs, std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...};
}
```

You are trying to do a comma expression but it is missing the outer () required to do a fold expression.  Instead what you want is

```
template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{std::invoke(fs, std::forward<Args>(args)...)...};
}
```

which doesn't have a `,`.  This expands out to

```
template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{std::invoke(fs1, fwd_arg1, fwd_arg2, ..., fwd_argN), 
                    std::invoke(fs2, fwd_arg1, fwd_arg2, ..., fwd_argN)
                    ...,
                    std::invoke(fsN, fwd_arg1, fwd_arg2, ..., fwd_argN);
}
```

---

One additional thing to note with your test case, the result will not be a

```
std::tuple{"lambda1: 42 abc"s, "lambda2: 42 abc"s}
```

but is instead

```
std::tuple{"lambda1: 42 abc"s, "lambda2: 42"s}
```

This is because `"abc"s` is a temporary so it gets moved into the first lambda and then you are left with an empty string for the rest of the lambdas.  Ideally you should not forward anything and just pass by value so everything is treated as an lvalue like

```
template <auto... fs, typename... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_all(Args &&...args) {
  return std::tuple{std::invoke(fs, args...)...};
}
```